# Calculate a point on a geodesic line on an ellipsoid

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, geodesy

I have a problem which i don't understand how to achieve. Maybe someone could sheed some light on it.

Have a look at this picture:

[image]

What I try to achieve is to determine the point D on the geodesic line AB with the minimal distance to C, given the points A, B, C. All points are on the surface of an ellipsoid with given latitude and longitude.

I know that in the plane I can use Vector Projection to determine D easily. But I don't know how to achieve this on an ellipsoid. To calculate the distances between the given points isn't a problem.

Comment: I'm confused. What "distance" you are referring to? The "geodesic" distance ( the length of the geodesic joining two points on the ellipsoid) or the regular Euclidean distance when you embed the ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I don't think "geodesic" distance is something that easy to calculate.

Comment: @achillehui I mean the distance between two points on the surface. This can be calculated f.e. by Vincenty's.